# Prevent website freezes when loading script from 3rd parties?

Tags: javascript, web, cdn

I'm working on a site that loads multiple scripts from different 3rd party sites. While working on the site I noticed the site freezes. At first I thought I did something wrong in my JavaScript file but after debugging I noticed one of the 3rd party site modernizr http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js
was held responsible for going offline for 5mins, but it went back to normal after that.

My question is how do I prevent my site from freezes if the 3rd party site is down in the future?